# Android Menu Item Dynamic Attributes

Tags: android, android-menu

If I am creating menu items dynamically and adding them with menu.add, how do I set the background color of the entire cell not just the text (spanning only changes the background of the text.  I need the entire cell background color changed - m is a custom Menu Object containing all of the info for a given menu item).

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(0, m.getIndex().ordinal(), Menu.NONE, m.getMenuTitle());
View v = menuItem.getActionView();
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after weeks of no replies I decided to scrap this and just use a ListView in my Drawer which allows me greater control and was able to accomplish what I needed